# INVALID_KEY_OR_REF when trying to create invoices with Suitescript

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I want to create invoices via suitescript.

I have tried the approach used here [How to create invoice using suitescript 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42939756/how-to-create-invoice-using-suitescript-2-0)

My code looks like this :

```
var objRecord = r.transform({
    fromType: r.Type.CUSTOMER,
    fromId: 1777,
    toType: r.Type.INVOICE,
    isDynamic: true
  });

  objRecord.setValue({
    fieldId: "entity",
    value: "1249",
    ignoreFieldChange: true
  });

  objRecord.setValue({
      fieldId: "location",
      value: "10",
      ignoreFieldChange: true
  });

  objRecord.setValue({
    fieldId: "exchangerate",
    value: "1.0",
    ignoreFieldChange: true
  });

  [...]
```

I always get a 'INVALID_KEY_OR_REF Invalid location reference key 10 ' error. 10 should be a valid location reference, since its used for some invoices of that customer already. I have tried using a different key(different location) aswell as setting the value without quotation marks. These approaches havent changed the error message.

How do i set the location for the invoice?

Comment: A location won't be available if the subsidiary is unset or set to a subsidiary that doesn't contain the location desired.

Comment: have tried to convert a saleOrdert to Invoice to avoid  add the customers and locations? **   var billRecord = record.transform({
                fromType: record.Type.SALES_ORDER,
                fromId: context.salesOrderInternalId,
                toType: record.Type.INVOICE,
                isDynamic: true
            }); **